# Returning async task from Web API Controller via ajax request as JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

In my MVC Controller, I had the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    var result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

    return result;
}
```

But now that I am using an MVC Web API, how do I change this to return a string and not a ActionResult via an Ajax request?

I tried the following and it works, but I get a string instead of a json object.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    String result =  await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Content = new ObjectContent<object>(result, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return resp;

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below solution to return the string content in response

`return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(// Your Object
     System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };`